# http status 200 instead of 304

Tags: http, get

I created a simple GET request script using Python to check the status code based on a custom header being passed in. Essentially, I am trying to check if the last modified time in the database is greater than or less than the last modified since time returned in the response.

The custom header parameter passed into the GET is:

```
If-Modified-Since: Tue, 10 Jul 2018 10:54:28 GMT
```

On some sites, I will get 200 if this is true, and 304 if this is false. However, on some sites I still get 200 even if it is false. I think what causes the faulty response is potentially the data being cached? I have a working knowledge of HTTP requests, but not enough to understand why this can occur, so I would appreciate some clarification if anyone can advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Servers can include [`cache-control` headers in their responses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) to not allow caching of the data they send. I'd imagine this could be a reason why you're getting a `200` instead of a `304`.